# Perl Mechanize throwing connection error while using proxy

Tags: perl, mechanize, perl-module, www-mechanize

I am trying to download pdf files present in a website using perl MECHANIZE module.
It worked fine when i am running the program without any proxy connection. But i am getting the below error when i tried to run the program on the company server which uses proxy connection.

error:

> Error GETing http://www.google.com: Can't connect to www.google.com:80
>   (10060) a t Download.pl line 20.

I am not sure if i need to add any proxy details in the program or Is this something that our company firewall is blocking programatical requests to a website ? 
I have tried a lot but coudn't find out. Can any one of you please suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you using some kind of LWP related module you could set the following shell variables

HTTP_PROXY=your.corp.proxy:your_proxy_port

You could check the connection with telnet or with wget

```
telnet www.google.com 80
```

with wget

```
wget http://www.google.com
```

---

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am working on windows 7. I have installed telnet client in windows to check the connection. I am not able to connect and the error message is as below "Connecting To www.google.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80
: Connect failed"

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify you proxy to the `$mech`:

```
 $mech->proxy(['http'], 'http://proxy_address:proxy_port/');
```